# Fetching all names from multiline string

Tags: php, regex, pcre, text-extraction

I was trying to fetch all names (with surnames) from multiline string plus message body but somehow it fetches only one name.

Example:

> Hi Marc, Stefanie El, Paul
>
> Congrats on the new job!
>
> I hope you’re feeling better this morning!

The regular expression that I'm using:

```
/(?<=^hi )(\W*(\w+ *\w*)+)*/gmi
```

As far as I understand the 1st caption group should repeatedly find as many names as possible, but it's not working in that way!

What mistake did I make with this regular expression?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure why you tagged `PCRE`, but this is how it could be done:

```
(?:\G(?!\A)|Hi\s*)
(?P<name>[A-Z][^,\n\r]+)
(?:,\h)?
```

See [**a demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/fKfnzF/1).

Comment: To be clear: `g` isn't specific to javascript and exists in pcre to express a global research, but it doesn't exist in PHP since a special method is used for that: `preg_match_all`. About C#: the .net regex engine isn't based on pcre.

Comment: The .net regex engine! that is able to have infinite lookbehinds, a right to left search, balanced groups, but no recursion, no `\K` feature, no possessive quantifiers (but atomic groups), no backtracking control verbs.

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte: Well then, thanks. Have updated the answer.

Comment: Don't forget to write that your pattern uses the x modifier.

Comment: Thanks a lot! But how can I fetch another lines as a message body? Is it possible to make in one regular expression?